# Poisson's Equation with unusual conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

Solve the boundary value problem:

$$Δu=f(r), 0<r<R, 0\leq θ\leq2 π,$$
$$u(R,θ)=g(θ), 0\leq θ\leq2 π.$$

Where $Δu$ denote $u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{θθ}$ and $R$ is a fix value. I know how to solve this problem when $f(r)=0$ or when $g(θ)=0$, but in this case I can't find the answer.

Anyone can help me please?.

Comment: Why not solve the two cases separately and then add them? After all, your equation is linear!

Comment: You are right, maybe this exercise is a bit obvious, was my bad, now finally I found the answer!! Thanks